# Laravel spatie no crea relación user roles

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, blade, spatie

** lo que pasa es que creo los roles, creo los permisos para los roles, pero cuando quiero utilizar el rol admin para visualizar una ruta me niega el acceso porque la relación no se crea y hago todo al pie de la letra como está en la documentación acá código del seederrol :**

```
class RoleSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     */
    public function run(): void
    {
        $role1 = Role::create([
            'name' => 'Admin',
        ]);   
        $role2 =Role::create([
            'name' => 'Cajero',
        ]);  
        $role3 = Role::create([
            'name' => 'Comercial',
        ]);  


// Rutas para manejar productos
$permissionsProductos = [
    'verActualizarPorduct', 'verImagen', 'deletePorduct',
    'indexPorduct', 'postPorduct', 'updatedProducto'
];
foreach ($permissionsProductos as $permissionProducto) {
    Permission::create(['name' => $permissionProducto])->syncRoles([$role1]);
}
```

** creo tres roles y le doy los permisos para crear los productos

```
este es el seeder para cerear el cliente :**
    public function run(): void
    {
        User::create([
            'name' => 'Admin',
            'email' => 'admin@localhost',
            'username'=> 'admin',
            'id_tienda'=>1,
            'password' => bcrypt('1234'),
        ])->assignRole('Admin');
    }
```

creo el cliente y le asigno el rol de admin, pero a la hora de hacer esto:

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'can:Admin'])->group(function () {
    Route::controller(ProductoController::class)->group(function () {
        Route::get('/actualizar/{id}', 'actualizarProducto')->name('verActualizarPorduct');
        Route::get('/imagenproducto/{path}', 'verImagen')->name('verImagen');
        Route::get('/delete/{id}', 'delete')->name('deletePorduct');
        Route::get('/productos/{id}', 'index')->name('indexPorduct');
        Route::post('/agregar_productos', 'crearProducto')->name('postPorduct');
        Route::post('update/producto/{id}', 'updateProducto')->name('updatedProducto');
        Route::post('/delete/{id}', 'delete')->name('deletePorduct');
    });
});
```

** no me autoriza el acceso a la ruta de ese usuario :
alguien sabe por qué por último dejo el modelo de users **

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
    use HasRoles;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'username',
        'password',
        
    ];
    

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'password' => 'hashed',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser por como defines el middleware, en tu caso es mejor definirlo por rol:

```
middleware(['role:Admin'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es un problema con el cache, assignRole no llama a un cache-reset

Fuente:
https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v6/advanced-usage/cache